# What is the reason why you cannot use the n value if a while condition loop

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to print the n value in the while loop but get AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'n'
What is the reason why I cannot access the n value

```
# Implement a sequence of power of 2's using a generator function.
def PowTwoGen(max = 1):
    n = 1
    while n <= max:
       result =  2 ** n
       yield result
       n += 1
    else:
       raise SystemExit
#
occurrence = PowTwoGen(4)
loopvalue = 1
for item in occurrence:
    print("n: " + str(loopvalue) + " Item = Result:  " + str(item))
#   print("n: " + str(occurrence.n) + " Item = Result:  " + str(item))
    loopvalue += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is a local variable - you can't access it like an attribute.

To solve your issue, you can instead yield `n` from the generator:

```
# Implement a sequence of power of 2's using a generator function.
def PowTwoGen(max = 1):
    n = 1
    while n <= max:
       result =  2 ** n
       yield n, result
       n += 1
    else:
       raise SystemExit
#
occurrence = PowTwoGen(4)
for loopvalue, item in occurrence:
    print("n: " + str(loopvalue) + " Item = Result:  " + str(item))
```

Output:

```
n: 1 Item = Result:  2
n: 2 Item = Result:  4
n: 3 Item = Result:  8
n: 4 Item = Result:  16
```